# PrintPreviewDialog issue on 4K monitor

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have added a print preview feature to my program. The problem is, it does not display the preview document well on screen resolutions above 1920 x 1080.

**Example:**

[image: preview]

**Code:**

```cpp
QFont docFont;
docFont.setPointSize(14);
QTextDocument *textDoc = new QTextDocument(this);
textDoc->setDefaultFont(docFont);
textDoc->setPlainText(getHardwareData());
```

During a debugging process I have found the following issues:

```
QWindowsMultiFontEngine::loadEngine: CreateFontFromLOGFONT failed for "Courier": error 0x88985002 : Indicates the specified font does not exist.
QWindowsMultiFontEngine::loadEngine: CreateFontFromLOGFONT failed for "Courier": error 0x88985002 : Indicates the specified font does not exist.
```

Is there any hint/font to make it look well on all screens resolutions?

**Edited:**
I have fixed the `QWindowsMultiFontEngine::loadEngine: CreateFontFromLOGFONT failed for "Courier"` issue. The problem was caused by a Unicode character in Peripheral data. Now, the only thing left is to make it look better on `4K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some hack to get the toolbar actions from a print preview dialog. By adding some additional logic it fixed the issue.

```
    QList<QToolBar*> toolbarList = printPreviewDlg->findChildren<QToolBar*>();

    if (!toolbarList.isEmpty()) {
        if (screenSize.width() > 1920 && screenSize.height() > 1080) {
            toolbarList.first()->actions().at(0)->activate(QAction::Trigger);
        } else {
            toolbarList.first()->actions().at(1)->activate(QAction::Trigger);
        }
    }
```

To detect the screen size I use the native `Win API` methods. Now, it automatically triggers the `Fit to width` toolbar option and sets a better preview on `4K` monitor. It works depending on the screen size. The issue is resolved.